# How do you display a name in v-select for a vue-dropdown?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

Im dynamically rendering a V-select in my vue-app by a computed property in my component, but my select is populated with [object Object] instead of the values. How can I set the name-property? Am I doing this wrong?

The dropdown is its own component:

```
<template>
    <v-select
      :items="listOfCompanys"
      label="Lokation"
      item-value="name"
      item-text="name"
      single-line
      bottom
    ></v-select>       
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'companydropdown',
  computed: {
    listOfCompanys () {
      return this.$store.state.users.userList
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The values im getting is like this:

[image]

Comment: what does you `userList` data structure look like?

Answer (score 10):

First of all, [`:items` of `v-select`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects) takes an array as argument:

> Name: `items` Default: `[]` Type: `Array`
>
> Can be an **array of objects or array of strings**. When using objects,
>   will look for a **`text`** and **`value`** field. This can be changed using
>   the **`item-text`** and **`item-value`** props.

So, if you are using:

```
<v-select
  :items="listOfCompanys"
  label="Lokation"
  item-value="name"
  item-text="name"
  single-line
  bottom
>
```

But is getting:

```
[object Object]
```

Then either:

- your `listOfCompanys` is an object (**not an array**); or
- your `listOfCompanys` a one-element array whose element is an object that does **not** have a property called `name` (because you configured `item-value="name"`).

#### Solution

- Make `listOfCompanys` an array of strings (e.g. `["John", "Smith"]`);

or

- Make `listOfCompanys` an array of objects having the properties:

  - `{name: "SomeName"}`, if you keep `item-value="name" item-text="name"`; or
  - `{value: 123, text: "Yoyo"}` if you remove the `item-value` and `item-text` properties; or
  - `{some1: "Bla", some2: 123}` if you have `item-value="some1"` and `item-text="some2"` (or vice-versa).

Check [**demo CodePen showing a solution here**](https://codepen.io/acdcjunior/pen/ddwveb?editors=1010).

Comment: For v3, 
`{some1: "Bla", some2: 123}` if you have `:reduce="item=>item.some1"` and `label="some2"` (or vice-versa)

Answer (score 3):

To show the items in VSelect you have to know what items the computed property returns.

> For example if the computed property returns an array like: ['one', 'two', 'three']... Then v-select will do the job itself.

If you have an array of objects vuetify thinks that the array looks like:

```
arr = [
  { text: 'name', value: 'John'},
  { text: 'name', value: 'Mike'}
  ...
]
```

In case that your objects doesn't have the above format you have to use `item-text` and `item-value` props to the VSelect. For example if the array looks like:

```
arr = [
 { header: 'name', column: 'name' },
 { header: 'lastName', column: 'lastName' }
]
```

You have to use VSelect as:

```
<v-select
  :items="items"
  item-text="header"
  item-value="column"
>
```

Answer (score -3):

i can solve v-select dynamic value pleace check my github link and follow the code

https://github.com/chirumist/vuetify-select2/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would be worth adding to your answer to explain why using this would help.