# Getting from DB returns [object Object] instead of value in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm creating a form using Vuetify with a dropdown option, however I want to get the dropdown choices from a table in my DB instead of hardcoding the options in.

It seems to be working, meaning that every new entry into the DB table increases the # of options I have in the dropdown. However, all it displays is [object Object]. How can I actually get it to display the actual value?

[image]

The dropdown component inside the template tag:

```
<v-card>
    <v-container>
        <v-col class="d-flex" cols="12">
            <v-select
            :items="allDropdownTypes"
            label="Project Type"
            >
            </v-select>
        </v-col>
    </v-container> 
</v-card>
```

The prop:

```
    props: {
        allDropdownTypes: Array
    },
```

My blade template:

```
<div>
    <project-form-v2 
    :all-dropdown-types="{{ $allDropdownTypes }}"
    >
    </project-form>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you display a name in v-select for a vue-dropdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49017322/how-do-you-display-a-name-in-v-select-for-a-vue-dropdown)

Comment: [object Object] is simply the default return value when converting an object to a string. You can see the the content of your object when converting to string by using JSON. stringify(). For this purpose, kindly read up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49017322/how-do-you-display-a-name-in-v-select-for-a-vue-dropdown)

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it:

```
<v-card>
    <v-container>
        <v-select
        :items="allDropdownTypes.map(a => a.value)"
        label="Project Type"
        >
        </v-select>
    </v-container>
</v-card>
```